# Is this passive voice?

Tags: grammar, writing-style, passive-voice, legalese

I am not sure if the below sentence is actually passive voice.

> Count I alleges negligence in Park Rangers’ removal of the signs.

If so - suggestions on rewording it without making the sentence very long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this sentence is active. For a sentence to be passive, it has to contain a form of *be* and a past participle (like *broken, worked, begun*), but the main verb is simply *alleges*, an active form.

What you probably mean is that the subject of the sentence (*Count I*) is not an agent, but something that can't really "do" anything. But that is about meaning only: active versus passive is mainly about syntax, the structure of a sentence.

An example of a passive sentence:

> In Count I, negligence in Park Rangers' removal of the signs **is alleged**.